# How to get out this error, exoplayer clashing my app

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer

I am trying to create simple video player in android studio, using `exoplayer` but i got this error

```
Process: com.example.smschecker, PID: 30203
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method addListener(Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer$EventListener;)V in class Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer' appears in /data/app/com.example.smschecker-2/base.apk)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlaybackControlView.setPlayer(PlaybackControlView.java:361)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(SimpleExoPlayerView.java:384)
        at com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails.iniPlayer(MovieDetails.java:137)
        at com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails.onStart(MovieDetails.java:120)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1244)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5648)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Below is the java code snippet.

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    iniPlayer();
}

private void iniPlayer() {
    String videoUr = "https://torrent243454.herokuapp.com/stream/magnet%3A%3Fxt%3Durn%3Abtih%3A65046701a31f23b2bb7e6d38537ca8498970d1ff%26dn%3DMortal.Kombat.Legends.Battle.of.the.Realms.2021.HDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO%26xl%3D1453573916%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.internetwarriors.net%3A1337%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Fopentor.org%3A2710%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252F9.rarbg.me%3A2980%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252F9.rarbg.to%3A2940%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.uw0.xyz%3A6969%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Fopen.stealth.si%3A80%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.torrent.eu.org%3A451%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Fipv4.tracker.harry.lu%3A80%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A1337%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Fexplodie.org%3A6969%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.tiny-vps.com%3A6969%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.moeking.me%3A6969%2Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.cyberia.is%3A6969%2Fannounce?file=Mortal.Kombat.Legends.Battle.of.the.Realms.2021.HDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO%2FMortal.Kombat.Legends.Battle.of.the.Realms.2021.HDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO.avi";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUr);
    SimpleExoPlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer1 = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(MovieDetails.this, trackSelector, loadControl);
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, factory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

   playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer1);
      playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
      simpleExoPlayer1.prepare(mediaSource);
      simpleExoPlayer1.setPlayWhenReady(true);
     simpleExoPlayer1.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, @Nullable Object manifest, int reason) {
             
         }

         @Override
         public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
             if (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING){
                 
             }
         }

         @Override
         public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onSeekProcessed() {

         }
     });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding event listener as like this

```
simpleExoPlayer1.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

            }
        });
```

Comment: i did like you said above but i still gives same error, please help me more

Comment: please share the library version that you are using

Comment: am not sure because iam begginer, implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.0'
.


    implementation'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:r2.4.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.4.0'

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

Comment: Android Studio 3.6.1
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897, built on February 26, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 x86
VM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 755M
Cores: 2
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.google.services.firebase